# java String index out of range 1111

Tags: java

There is a 1102 characters length of encoded message which is passes to the function read() and this function decode the encoded message.
I have already explained the working of the function read() in comments.
      Successfully compiled but there is a exception "String index out of range: 1111". I m not getting the reason.

```
public class SecretMessage
{
    private String encodedMessage;

    public SecretMessage(String encodedMessage)
    {
        this.encodedMessage = encodedMessage;
    }

    /**
     * Reads every 10th letter of encodedMessage and returns a string
     * with the letters it reads.
     * @return A message hidden in the garbled text
     */
    public String read()
    {
        String decodedMessage = "";
     int lenEncode = encodedMessage.length();
     int count = 0;
     for(int i = 0; i < lenEncode; i++)
     {

        String update = encodedMessage.substring(count, count + 1);
        count = count + 10;
        decodedMessage = decodedMessage + update; 
        }
        return decodedMessage;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're getting the value of `count` from the string, but checking against `i`.

Comment: If you used a debugger you would be able to see that `count` is every multiple of `10` and the first multiple of `10` which is out of range (as you don't check this value) is `1111`.  When you enter the method it checks the end index before checking you have a valid start index which is why it complains about `1111` rather than your start which is `1110`

Comment: The code you've posted won't compile. There is an extra `}`. Also, the indentation is inconsistent.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i = 0; i < lenEncode; i++)
{
    String update = encodedMessage.substring(count, count + 1);
    count = count + 10;
    decodedMessage = decodedMessage + update; 
}
return decodedMessage;
}
```

First off why are you not checking against `i`?

Second there are two potential problems in this:
`count + 1` will hit a number that is higher than the last index in the array even if you use `i` instead of `count`.

Also `count = count + 10` is the current issue you're having. This is guaranteed to become greater than `lenEncode`!

Answer (score 0):

This will gonna decode your message. it will pick the `charAt(10+x)` from the encoded message

```
public class SecretMessage
{
    private String encodedMessage;

    public SecretMessage(String encodedMessage)
    {
        this.encodedMessage = encodedMessage;
    }

    /**
     * Reads every 10th letter of encodedMessage and returns a string
     * with the letters it reads.
     * @return A message hidden in the garbled text
     */
    public String read()
    {
        String decodedMessage = "";
     int lenEncode = encodedMessage.length();
     for(int i = 0; (i+1) < lenEncode; i+=10)
     {

        String update = encodedMessage.substring(i, i + 1);

        decodedMessage = decodedMessage + update; 
        }
        return decodedMessage;
    }
}
```

Comment: This should still throw an exception when `i = lenEncode - 1`

Comment: I don't think so ... please try then let me know.

Comment: `lenEncode` is highest index + 1. this means when `substring(i, i+1)` is called for `i = lenEncode - 1`, it will try to reference an index that is beyond the limits of the String.

Comment: @Dragondraikk, the code is fine, the IndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown only if you use a value higher than the String length. You can use the String length as the second parameter of the substring method. [substring documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-)

Comment: @junaid its still throwing an exception

Comment: @shubhendrasinghSolanki I have updated my answer. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the condition of your for loop, you try to read at the count position but you are using the i counter to iterate over the String.

You can replace the loop condition for something like that:

```
for(int count = 0; count < lenEncode; count += 10)
```

By the way, you are creating a new String each time you add a letter, the performance could be very bad for long Strings, you could consider using a StringBuilder.

```
/**
 * Reads every 10th letter of encodedMessage and returns a string
 * with the letters it reads.
 * @return A message hidden in the garbled text
 */
public String read()
{
    int lenEncode = encodedMessage.length();
    StringBuilder decodedMessage = new StringBuilder();
    for(int count = 0; count < lenEncode; count += 10)
    {
        char character = encodedMessage.charAt(count);
        decodedMessage.append(character);
    }
    return decodedMessage.toString();
}
```

Comment: Unless its a multi threaded environment StringBuffer is better than StringBuilder.

Comment: StringBuffer is threadSafe and StringBuilder is not so StringBuilder is slightly better if synchronization is not required. Anyway, the difference in performance between creating new Strings each time and create a String using StringBuffer or StringBuilder is much bigger than the difference between using StringBuffer or StringBuilder.

Answer (score -1):

change this

```
for(int i = 0; i < lenEncode; i++)
```

{...

with this

```
for(int count = 0; count < lenEncode-1; count+=10)
```

{...

Comment: That won't help as `count = i * 10` not `i + 10`

Comment: You can skip the last character of the String with `count < lenEncode-1`. You should use: `for(int count = 0; count < lenEncode; count += 10)` instead.